# Setup of mvc-mini-profiler for EF-db- first

Tags: entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to use the mini-profiler with old-style EF code - database-first.

So far:

- I've created a db context using:

  ```
      string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
      var connection = new EntityConnection(connectionString);
      var profiledConnection = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(connection);
      _context = profiledConnection.CreateObjectContext<MyEntitiesType>();
  ```
- but then I hit a "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed."
  which I worked around using a `<system.data>` reference to the MvcMiniProfiler provider:

  ```
   <system.data>
     <DbProviderFactories>
       <remove invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" />
       <add name="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" description="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" type="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProviderFactory, MvcMiniProfiler" />
      </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
  ```
- but now I'm hitting a stack overflow somewhere in `C:\Users\sam\Desktop\mvc-mini-profiler\MvcMiniProfiler\Data\ProfiledDbProviderServices.cs`. Looking at the [latest source](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/Data/ProfiledDbProviderServices.cs) I'm wondering if I've somehow got the setup wrong for this - if somehow my profiled connection is containing another profiled connection is containing....

Any help/advice?

---

Update - looking at http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions at least one other person has seen the same sort of problem with 1.7 - although (s)he's doing code first. I'll keep playing to see if I can work out what to do...

Comment: does this help? http://benjii.me/2011/07/using-the-mvc-mini-profiler-with-entity-framework/ there is another proposal for a way to profile EF

Comment: Maybe - will have to try it out - will either happen late tomorrow night or Friday (at a client site all day tomorrow)

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to set it up with EF database first?

Comment: @RyanW - no - I think I'll download the source and try properly at some point (sorry for delay - been away on hols)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 1.9. With the update, I just added the new Initialize method in Application_Start and removed the DbProviderFactories config section and now I have SQL profiling with EF (2 databases even, one with code first and one with database first).

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ....other code

    MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: OK - good news - it does seem to have been fixed! Thanks RyanW.

Comment: @RyanW Guess you didn't try this with Oracle databases, right?

Comment: Seems to be working fine with the current version, 2.1.0, with database first.

Comment: @JamesSkemp seems not to be, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195200/miniprofiler-setup-a-null-was-returned-after-calling-the-get-providerfactory)

Comment: @VahidND - interesting. I had hooked it up on that date just fine with a new project.